# How to get the same width for every bar in this geom_col() with position_dodge() in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, position, bar-chart

I'm trying to reproduce the following plot:

[image]

So far, I have produced the following code in R:

```
library(tidyverse)

tribble(~attribute, ~level, ~importance_score,
        "Price", "$70 per month", -0.18,
        "Price", "$50 per month", 0,
        "Price", "$30 per month", 0.18,
        "Data included", "500MB", -0.25,
        "Data included", "1GB", -0.10,
        "Data included", "10GB", 0.11,
        "Data included", "Unlimited", 0.23,
        "International minutes included", "0 min", -0.01,
        "International minutes included", "90 min", -0.01,
        "International minutes included", "300 min", 0.02,
        "SMS included", "300 messages", -0.06,
        "SMS included", "Unlimited text", 0.06) %>% 
  mutate(id = 1:nrow(.)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(id)) %>% 
  mutate(attribute = as_factor(attribute),
         level = as_factor(level)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(attribute, importance_score, fill = level)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.5, position = position_dodge(0.75)) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-0.4, 0.4, by = 0.1), limits = c(-0.35, 0.35)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("$70 per month" = "#721817",
                               "$50 per month" = "#721817",
                               "$30 per month" = "#721817",
                               "500 MB" = "#fa9f42",
                               "1GB" = "#fa9f42",
                               "10GB" = "#fa9f42",
                               "Unlimited" = "#fa9f42",
                               "0 min" = "#2b4162",
                               "90 min" = "#2b4162",
                               "300 min" = "#2b4162",
                               "300 messages" = "#0b6e4f",
                               "Unlimited text" = "#0b6e4f")) +
  labs(y = "Relative value", x = "Levels by attribute") +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = "gray95", linetype = 1, size = 1),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        text = element_text(size = 15))
```

which outputs the following plot:

[image]

My question is, how would you go about controlling the `width` argument in `geom_col()` without messing up the `position = position_dodge()` argument, which allows the plot to group by the "attribute" variable? **What I want is to have the same width for every bar in this plot** and also, to have the same distance between each grouping variable.

When I use `position = position_dodge(0.75, preserve = "single")`, I get:

[image]

In this case, it is not as clear to see in this plot, but: the length is not the same among the two green brackets I drew on top of the plot. **How do I solve this**?

Comment: Try with `position = position_dodge(0.75, preserve = "single")`

Comment: Hi @stefan, thank you so much for you reply, it did help. Nevertheless, a new problem appeared and the length is not the same for the two green brackets I drew on top of the new plot (i.e., the distance among the two grouping variables is different). See the edits for more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to make use of `facet_grid` like so:

1. Map `factor(id)` on `y` instead of `atrribute`
2. Facet by `attribute`. Add `scales="free_y"` and `space=free_y`
3. Style the strip texts and get rid of axis labels and ticks via `theme`options.
4. To add some space between groups of bars you could adjust the expansion of the `y` scale

Note: As far as I get it you could map `attribute` on `fill` which would simplify your `scale_fill_manual` as you only need to set four colors.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dd <- dd %>% 
  mutate(id = 1:nrow(.)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(id)) %>% 
  mutate(attribute = forcats::fct_rev(as_factor(attribute)),
          level = as_factor(level))

ggplot(dd, aes(importance_score, factor(id), fill = attribute)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-0.4, 0.4, by = 0.1), limits = c(-0.35, 0.35), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = expansion(add = c(1, 1))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Price" = "#721817", 
                               "Data included" = "#fa9f42",
                               "International minutes included" = "#2b4162",
                               "SMS included" = "#0b6e4f")) +
  labs(y = "Relative value", x = "Levels by attribute") +
  facet_grid(attribute ~ ., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y", switch = "y") +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = "gray95", linetype = 1, size = 1),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none",
        text = element_text(size = 15),
        strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 360, hjust = 1),
        strip.background.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length.y = unit(0, "pt"),
        panel.spacing.y = unit(0, "pt")
        )
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
dd <- tribble(~attribute, ~level, ~importance_score,
        "Price", "$70 per month", -0.18,
        "Price", "$50 per month", 0,
        "Price", "$30 per month", 0.18,
        "Data included", "500MB", -0.25,
        "Data included", "1GB", -0.10,
        "Data included", "10GB", 0.11,
        "Data included", "Unlimited", 0.23,
        "International minutes included", "0 min", -0.01,
        "International minutes included", "90 min", -0.01,
        "International minutes included", "300 min", 0.02,
        "SMS included", "300 messages", -0.06,
        "SMS included", "Unlimited text", 0.06)
```